# Why expo/tsconfig.base uses moduleResolution node?

Tags: typescript, expo, package.json, monorepo, tsconfig

Why expo `tsconfig.base` uses `"moduleResolution": "node"` instead for example `"moduleResolution": "node16"`.

I'm asking this because I'm working in a monorepo and I'm creating a shared library with functions to access backend api. My plan was to export every feature separatly using the `"exports"` `package.json` option.

for example

```
// package.json
"name": "@foo/api",
"exports": {
  "./auth": "./src/auth.ts",
  "./config": "./src/config.ts",
  "./user": "./src/user/index.ts
},
```

But it is not working because of the `"moduleResolution": "node"`.

Should I just export everything from a single file and add only a `"main"` option or do something else?